# ExecuteNonQuery is not working when using dynamic SQL to update

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, dynamic-sql

I've tried to use the `ExecuteNonQuery()` to update a table using the `SqlCommand`. However, nothing happened. I'd like to know what happened. I've run the same command in SSMS and everything worked successfully. Don't know why it doesn't work on my C# code (.NET 4.6).

Thank you!

[AppUser Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5psMY.png)

[Department Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLPMG.png)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp_StoredProc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string columnName = "DepartmentId";
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
            string commandText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('Test.dbo.AppUser') and name = '"+columnName+"') " +
                "UPDATE Test.dbo.AppUser SET ["+columnName+ "] = @deptId where Id = @id";
            int rowUpdated = 0;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
                {
                    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@deptId", 2);
                    SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@id", 4);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

                    cmd.CommandText = commandText;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    conn.Open();
                    rowUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(rowUpdated);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `commandText` look like when you inspect it, before calling `ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: ```"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('Test.dbo.AppUser') and name = 'DepartmentId') UPDATE Test.dbo.AppUser SET [DepartmentId] = @deptId where Id = @id"```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `EXISTS` statement, does the `AppUser` table get updated?

Comment: Hi Trevor, it worked! Shall I execute `EXISTS` command separately to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: What is in `ConnectionString`? If you're not in the context of the `Test` database then `sys.columns` will be in whatever database context you have. So try `Test.sys.columns` or make sure you're connecting to the right database in the first place...